# getting error while using update Query - No value is given for one or more required parameter

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am getting the error while using the below mentioned update query.
the error is

> No value is given for one or more parameter

```
Public Function UpdateDistinctColumnFRNumberBasis()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim objConn As Object
Dim objRecordSet As Object

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objRecCmd_Update = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
         MergedInvoiceFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;""")
StrInvoiceNumber = "109839-01"
FRSparepartNumber = "FT7119907459"
MergedInvoiceFile  = "/test.xlsx"
strSQL = ""

strSQL = "Update [Tabelle1$] SET"

strSQL = strSQL + " [Test] = 'Distinct' "

strSQL =  " Update [Tabelle1$] SET [Test] = 'Distinct' Where ([RECHNR] ='" & _
   StrInvoiceNumber & "' AND [TEILENUMMER] = " & FRSparepartNumber & ")"

objConn.Execute strSQL

objConn.Close

Set objConn = Nothing
Set objRecCmd = Nothing
Set objRecCmd_Update = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: `FRSparepartNumber` is not numeric, so it needs to be quoted like `StrInvoiceNumber`

Answer (score 0):

In case Tim's answer was not clear enough for you, try this modification:

```
strSQL =  " Update [Tabelle1$] SET [Test] = 'Distinct' Where ([RECHNR] ='" & _
   StrInvoiceNumber & "' AND [TEILENUMMER] = '" & FRSparepartNumber & "')"
```

Comment: Hi , I have added quotes in FR sparepart number just like Invoice number , but now I am getting data mismatch in the criteria expression.

Comment: That sounds like you are trying to check for equality between a number and a string.  It will be helpful for you (and me) to see the full SQL statement before you try to execute it.  Put "Debug.Print strSQL" just before "objConn.Execute strSQL"  My guess is that either  RECHNR or TEILENUMMER is expecting a number but the value provided is a string of characters

Comment: Update [Tabelle1$] SET [Distinct] = 'Distinct' Where ([RECHNR] ='010541-01' AND [TEILENUMMER] = 'FT99999000006') . This is the Query

Comment: So, you are trying to update a record in your data that has a TEILENUMMER of FT99999000006.  Are you able to find that record by hand?  Without seeing your data, my hunch is that the real value should be 99999000006

Comment: I have a value FT99999000006 in the TELIENUMMER column, I am able to find that in hand

Comment: I'm not sure.  A couple of other things that look unusual to me are:  1) "distinct" is a reserved word in SQL, so having it as a column name could be a problem. 2) having the dollar sign ($) on the table name also seems unusual

Comment: the name of the sheet in excel is Tabelle1 , $ sign is used inside the sql statement in VBA.

Comment: if you are available to zoom, I can take a look.  hop on the following link.  I'll be available for the next hour.  https://byu.zoom.us/j/98355170129

Comment: Hi ,  Yes . can we connect now